# Laravel rename routing resource path names

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

Can we rename routing resource path names in Laravel like in Ruby on Rails?

Current

```
/users/create  ->  UsersController@create
/users/3/edit  ->  UsersController@edit
```

..
I want like this;

```
/users/yeni  ->  UsersController@create
/users/3/duzenle  ->  UsersController@edit
```

I want to do this for localization.

---

Example from Ruby on Rails;

```
scope(path_names: { new: "ekle" }) do
  resources :users
end
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I know this is an old question. I'm just posting this answer for historical purposes:

Laravel now has the possibility to localize the resources. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#restful-localizing-resource-uris

> Localizing Resource URIs By default, Route::resource will create
>   resource URIs using English verbs. If you need to localize the  create
>   and edit action verbs, you may use the Route::resourceVerbs method.
>   This may be done in the boot method of your AppServiceProvider:
>
> ```
> use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
>
> /**
>  * Bootstrap any application services.
>  *
>  * @return void
>  */
>
> public function boot() {
>     Route::resourceVerbs([
>         'create' => 'crear',
>         'edit' => 'editar',
>     ]); }
> ```
>
> Once the verbs have been customized, a resource route registration such as  Route::resource('fotos', 'PhotoController') will
>   produce the following URIs:
>
> ```
> /fotos/crear
>
> /fotos/{foto}/editar
> ```

Answer (score 1):

It ain't pretty, but you could define multiple routes that use the same controller function. For example:

```
Route::get("user/create", "UsersController@create");
Route::get("user/yeni", "UsersController@create");
```

The only (glaringly obvious downside) being that you're routes will get quite cluttered quite quickly. There is a setting in `app/config/app.php` where you can set/change your locale, and it could be possible to use that in conjunction with a filter to use the routes and then group those routes based on the current local/language, but that would require more research.

As far as I know, there isn't a way to rename resource routes on the fly, but if you get creative you can figure something out. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the resource url's.
For this you will need to define/create each route according your needs

```
Route::get("user/yeni", "UsersController@create");
```

and if you need more than one languages you can use the `trans` helper function, which is an alias for the `Lang::get` method

```
Route::get('user/'.trans('routes.create'), 'UsersController@create');
```

Comment: Thanks Philips but you can rename methods with this. I want to rename url.

Comment: @tgezginis sorry, i thought that you wanted to change the names. Fixed my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue. And managed to recreate some sort of custom resource route method. It probably could be a lot better, but for now it works like a charm.

```
namespace App\Helpers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;

class RouteHelper
{
    public static function NamedResourceRoute($route, $controller, $named, $except = array())
    {
        $routes = RouteHelper::GetDefaultResourceRoutes($route);
        foreach($routes as $method => $options) {
            RouteHelper::GetRoute($route, $controller, $method, $options['type'], $options['name'], $named);
        }
    }

    public static function GetRoute($route, $controller, $method, $type, $name, $named) {
        App::make('router')->$type($named.'/'.$name, ['as' => $route.'.'.$method, 'uses' => $controller.'@'.$method]);
    }
    public static function GetDefaultResourceRoutes($route) {
       return [
        'store' => [
            'type' => 'post',
            'name' => ''
        ],
        'index' => [
            'type' => 'get',
            'name' => ''
        ],
        'create' => [
            'type' => 'get',
            'name' => trans('routes.create')
        ],
        'update' => [
            'type' => 'put',
            'name' => '{'.$route.'}'
        ],
        'show' => [
            'type' => 'get',
            'name' => '{'.$route.'}'
        ],
        'destroy' => [
            'type' => 'delete',
            'name' => '{'.$route.'}'
        ],
        'edit' => [
            'type' => 'get',
            'name' => '{'.$route.'}/'.trans('routes.edit')
        ]
    ];
}
}
```

Use it like this in the routes.php:

```
\App\Helpers\RouteHelper::NamedResourceRoute('recipes', 'RecipeController', 'recepten');
```

Where the first parameter is for the named route, second the controller and third the route itself.

And something like this to the view/lang/{language}/route.php file:

```
'edit' => 'wijzig',
'create' => 'nieuw'
```

This results in something like this:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible in Laravel as they use code by convention over configuration. A resources uses the RESTfull implementation

Therefore you have to stick to the convention of

```
GET   /news/create
POST  /news
GET   /news/1
GET   /news/1/edit
...
```

Comment: you can not use resources and define the routes manually (or write your own method which does the same thing (have a look at the source code of Route for inspiration ;-) )

Comment: I'm afraid that this isn't true any longer, see the (now) accepted answer.