# Restful resource Controllers user login/logout

Tags: php, laravel, controller, restful-authentication

I am creating a page for user signup,login and logout. I have to use Restful resource Controllers. I have a resource as below

```
 Route::resource('sessions', 'SessionsController',
 ['only' => ['create', 'store', 'destroy']]);
```

Now for user login I am using create() but, in this case my URI looks like localhost/sessions/create. I want it to look like localhost/sessions/login and logout instead of create, destroy etc. Is there a way I can use restful but my URI has login,logout instead of create,destroy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't manipulate this, you just have to create the routes manually in your routes file. Though to be honest this shouldn't be an issue as it's only a couple of extra lines in the routes.php file?

Similar question asked here: [Laravel rename routing resource path names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27806257/laravel-rename-routing-resource-path-names)

Comment: Route::get('login','SessionsController@index');

Route::get('logout','SessionsController@destroy');

Route::resource('sessions', 'SessionsController', ['only' => ['create','store','destroy']]);

This is what I ended up doing but I was wondering if i add the routes manually is it still the "Restful resource controllers" sorry I am very new and one of the limitations is that i shall use restful controllers.

Comment: remember that not using 'RESTful resource controllers' does not mean you are violating REST principles in your application. RESTful resource controllers are just a 'convenience' Laravel provides to get you up and running quick